# When uploading file in Visual Studio Development works but not when the website has been published

Tags: c#, iis

I have a page where the user the can upload a csv file, this will then be saved in the database and displayed in in a gridview.   This all works fine when developing the site, but when I publish the site to IIS and access it externally it gives and error of "500 internal server error" When trying to uplaod the file

This is the code I am using to upload the files:

```
private string GetConnectionString()
{
    return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OfficeConnection"].ConnectionString;
}

private void CreateDatabaseTable(DataTable dt, string tableName)
{
    string sqlQuery = string.Empty;
    string sqlDBType = string.Empty;
    string dataType = string.Empty;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendFormat(string.Format("CREATE TABLE {0} (", tableName));

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        int maxLength = 0;
        dataType = dt.Columns[i].DataType.ToString();
        if (dataType == "System.Int32")
        {
            sqlDBType = "INT";
        }
        else if (dataType == "System.String")
        {
            sqlDBType = "NVARCHAR";
            maxLength = dt.Columns[i].MaxLength;
        }
        else
        {
            //do something else
        }

        if (maxLength > 0)
            sb.AppendFormat(string.Format("{0} {1} ({2}), ", dt.Columns[i].ColumnName, sqlDBType, maxLength));
        else
            sb.AppendFormat(string.Format("{0} {1},", dt.Columns[i].ColumnName, sqlDBType));
    }

    sqlQuery = sb.ToString();
    sqlQuery = sqlQuery.Trim().TrimEnd(',');
    sqlQuery = sqlQuery + " )";

    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn))
        {
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
    }
}

private void LoadDataToDatabase(string tableName, string fileFullPath, string delimeter)
{
    string sqlQuery = string.Empty;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendFormat(string.Format("BULK INSERT {0} ", tableName));
    sb.AppendFormat(string.Format(" FROM '{0}'", fileFullPath));
    sb.AppendFormat(string.Format(" WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = '{0}' , ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' )", delimeter));
    sqlQuery = sb.ToString();

    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn))
        {
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
    }
}

private void UploadAndProcessFile()
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        if (fileInfo.Name.Contains(".csv"))
        {
            string fileName = fileInfo.Name.Replace(".csv", "").ToString();
            string csvFilePath = Server.MapPath("UploadedCSVFiles") + "\\" + fileInfo.Name;

            //Save the CSV file in the Server inside 'UploadedCSVFiles'   
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(csvFilePath);

            //Fetch the location of CSV file   
            string filePath = Server.MapPath("UploadedCSVFiles") + "\\";

            string strSql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", fileInfo.Name);
            string strCSVConnString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;'", filePath);

            // load the data from CSV to DataTable   
            DataTable dtCSV = new DataTable();
            DataTable dtSchema = new DataTable();
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, strCSVConnString))
            {
                adapter.FillSchema(dtCSV, SchemaType.Mapped);
                adapter.Fill(dtCSV);
            }

            if (dtCSV.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                CreateDatabaseTable(dtCSV, fileName);
                Label2.Text = string.Format("The table ({0}) has been successfully created to the database.", fileName);
                string fileFullPath = filePath + fileInfo.Name;
                LoadDataToDatabase(fileName, fileFullPath, ",");
                Label1.Text = string.Format("({0}) records has been loaded to the table {1}.", dtCSV.Rows.Count, fileName);
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "File is empty.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "Unable to recognize file.";
        }
    }
}

protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UploadAndProcessFile();
}
```

Is this a setting in IIS I need to change?  I have checked the permission on the site and all is fine.

Thanks

Comment: Learn how to capture unhandled exceptions, and then you will see the cause.

Comment: Could you share what is the size of the file you are trying to upload?iis default file upload size limit is 4 MB.